# How to Build and Download C# Debug Folder Directly via Local Machine - Azure DevOps Services TFVC

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have hosted C# windows application source code to Azure DevOps Services (TFVC).

How can i build and download debug folder directly via the local machine without running the pipeline from DevOps portal ?

is creating pipeline mandatory to build and archive the debug folder ? is it possible to do directly via visual studio 2019 ? or is using Azure CLI command the only option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the code files from your TFVC repository onto your local machine, then open the code using [**Source Control Explorer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-source-control-explorer-manage-files-under-version-control?view=azure-devops) in Visual Studio to view, edit it. Once you can open the code in Visual Studio, you can directly build it in Visual Studio.